# ¿Qué falta en el disparador?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo que hacer esto Disparador SinComis que velará que la comisión será nula para los empleados que no pertenezcan a los departamentos 110, 111 y 112. Si se intenta asignar comisión a esos empleados, el disparador la pondrá a nula y no emitirá ni código ni mensaje de error, solo un mensaje por pantalla que informe: “El empleado no pertenece a departamentos comerciales por lo que su comisión se ha puesto a nula”.

Esta es la bd https://www.dropbox.com/s/2v4jgswdp4ux8bd/CreaTrasCor.SQL?dl=0

Mi problema es que no se como poner a nula la comisión os pongo lo que he hecho

```
   CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER SinComis 
    BEFORE insert or update of comis on TEMPLE for each row
declare
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
    if (inserting or updating and :new.comis !=:null) then
        update temple set temple.comis = null
        where temple.NUMDE != 110 or temple.NUMDE != 111 or temple.NUMDE != 112;
        bms_output.put_line('El empleado no pertenece a departamentos comerciales por lo que su comisión se ha puesto a nula');
end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: En tu condicional no estas evaluando si el empleado pertenece a alguno de los departamentos, sino que evalúas si la comisión no es nula. La respuesta la tienes en esta linea de tu pregunta: **la comisión será nula para los empleados que no pertenezcan a los departamentos 110, 111 y 112**. Por lo tanto debes verificar si el empleado no pertenece a alguno de dichos departamentos, si ese es el caso, entonces la comisión será puesta nula y se mostrará el mensaje. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras lo he corregido a ver que te parece

Comment: Por lo que puedo ver estás repitiendo cosas, si no me equivoco. Tienes: `for each row`, por lo tanto al realizar un `update`, por cada fila que vayas a actualizar realizas otro `update`, y realmente no es eso lo que quieres. Que tal si tu condición la pones así: `if (inserting or updating and (:new.NUMDE NOT BETWEEN 110 and 112)) then :new.comis := null; ...`. Creo que eso es lo que estás buscando. Saludos

Comment: lo veo muchas gracias